# Distributing installer of Windows desktop application

Tags: windows, deployment, amazon-s3, installation, hosting

I have an installer for my Windows app and it is quite big (>100 Mb).

I am also using ClickOnce deployment framework, so each time I issue an update all my users have to download the installer. We tried to use Amazon S3 to store the setup file, but it turns out that download speeds differ significantly across the globe, e.g. in US the download speed is several Mbps while in Europe or China it is less than 30Kbps, which is inapplicable.

However when I download most of the apps from internet, the download speed is usually good and doesn't depend this much on server location. How is this problem usually solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big companies like Microsoft use a content delivery network which makes sure no matter where you come from a download server gets assigned to you which is as near as possible to your current location.

Comment: Ok, actually I should've googled "Content delivery network". Turns out Amazon has it's own one called CloudFront, I think I can use that if it's any good. Thank you!